# Maths Range To Percentage

Tags: math, language-agnostic

i need a bit of help with some maths.

I have a range 0 - 127 and i want to convert it into percentage.

So 0% = 0 and 100% = 127 and every number inbetween.

How would i do this?

Edit:

Thanks to what jon posted, i came up with:

$percent * 127 / 100

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to go from a value to a percentage, eg from 63.5 to 50%, divide your value by 127 & multiply by 100.

If you want to go the other way, eg from 50% to 63.5, it's the reverse: divide your percentage by 100 & multiply by 127.

Comment: Also if you're using this in a programming language that you might need to convert to a float or the value will get truncated.

Comment: How would i do that, the other way round?

Answer (score 49):

While Jon's answer was not incorrect, the answer given by belisarius was more complete, in that it allowed for a range of numbers beginning and ending with any number, and not necessarily starting with 0.

Here's a little better way to represent the formula:

```
percentage = (value - min) / (max - min)
```

If you want to represent the percentage as a whole number instead of a decimal, simply multiply the result by 100.

And here's the reverse (going from a percentage to a value):

```
value = ((max - min) * percentage) + min
```

The percentage here is a decimal. If your percentage is a whole number, simply divide it by 100 before inserting in this formula.

Comment: Does a formula like this exist for any range, not only from min to max like 0 -> 20 but also something like 20 -> 0, so that when the percentage increases the value decreases until 100% is 0?

Answer (score 22):

Generally, if you have numbers in the interval [a,b], to get the percentage inside your interval, the formula is:

```
percentage = 100 * (x-a) / (b-a)
```

Where x is your value