# Lightweight scrollUp function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

Trying to make simple jQuery function to create a scrollToTop button that fades in as you scroll down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = 300;
    var duration = 200;
    var scrolled;

    $('.scrollUp').css('opacity', '0.0');

    $(window).scroll(function(){ 

        var opacity = (scrolled - start) / duration;

        scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (0 < opacity < 1) {
            $('.scrollUp').css('display', 'block').css('opacity', opacity);
        } else if (1 < opacity) {
            $('.scrollUp').css('display', 'block').css('opacity', '1.0');
        } else {
            $('.scrollUp').css('display', 'none').css('opacity', '0.0');
        }
    });

    $('.scrollUp').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/fBvGH/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, tested in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBvGH/17/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = 300;
    var duration = 200;
    var scrolled;

    $('.scrollUp').css('opacity', '0.0');

    $(window).scroll(function(){ 

        var opacity = (scrolled - start) / duration;

        scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (0 < opacity < 1) {
            $('.scrollUp').css('display', 'block').css('opacity', opacity);
        } else if (1 < opacity) {
            $('.scrollUp').css('display', 'block').css('opacity', '1.0');
        } else {
            $('.scrollUp').css('display', 'none').css('opacity', '0.0');
        }
    });

    $('.scrollUp').click(function(){
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

---

#### Update:

And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/fBvGH/40/) a working example with the opacity animation.
Looks like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241492/maths-range-to-percentage) was looking for the same equation.

Better to use some math in situation's like this:

```
scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
height = $('body').height();
height = Math.ceil((scrolled / height) * 100);
height = height / 100;
```

---

#### Second Update

Ok, you want it to start appearing after the dark blue section. Ok, so what you need to do is exclude that portion of the top before the gradient. You can do that by making an if clause that checks if the scrollTop value has hit the top part of the light blue gradient; around 300px from the top of the document. [image: jsFiddle diagram] 
 Then instead of using the body height in the above equation, use the total height of the gradient section; about 210px. This value will replace the var height in the jQuery above. Let me know if you have issues implementing this. Didn't notice you're comment on the above answer.

Comment: That's close but do you see the gradient?

Comment: The gradient on the body element? Are you trying to fade that also?
If so, in what manner?

Comment: yeah i managed to figure it out on my own, turns out I used incorrect formatting for the math

Comment: Yeah, it works the first time, but scroll up and down a couple times.
The fade starts occurring at different offsets from the top. Might want to try some sort of reset mechanism to zero out the opacity level when the user scrolls back up. Just a suggestion ;]

Answer (score 1):

`scrollTop` is not a `window` property, so just change you code slightly:
`$(window).animate({scrollTop : 0},500);`

to

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},500);`

here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fBvGH/13/

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize that but other than that its not fading in the way I would expect it to.

Comment: thats not what I meant, its supposed to start fading in after 300 pixels and finish when it reaches 500